# R filter | Filtering and grouping with condition

Tags: r, filter

I have been stuck on this for a while, if anyone can please help. I have a data set which looks like this

```
Col1 Date           Value
A    2019-01-01      NA
A    2019-01-02      4
A    2019-01-03      NA
B    2019-02-01      NA
B    2019-02-02      NA
B    2019-02-03      1
C    2019-03-01      NA
C    2019-03-02      NA
C    2019-03-03      NA
```

I want to create a table which for each unique A/B/C gives out row which has a value in 'Value' column or the first row if there is none (*like in case of C*), i.e., the resulting output should look like

```
    Col1 Date           Value
    A    2019-01-02      4
    B    2019-02-03      1
    C    2019-03-01      NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can group by 'Col1', `slice` the first non- NA row or `if` all 'Value' are `NA`, return the first row

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(Col1) %>%
   slice(if(all(is.na(Value))) 1 else which(!is.na(Value))[1])
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Col1 [3]
#  Col1  Date       Value
#  <chr> <chr>      <int>
#1 A     2019-01-02     4
#2 B     2019-02-03     1
#3 C     2019-03-01    NA
```

---

Or another option is to `arrange` first and then do the `slice` on the first row

```
df1 %>% 
     group_by(Col1) %>%
     arrange(is.na(Value), .by_group = TRUE) %>%
     slice(1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Col1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", 
"C"), Date = c("2019-01-01", "2019-01-02", "2019-01-03", "2019-02-01", 
"2019-02-02", "2019-02-03", "2019-03-01", "2019-03-02", "2019-03-03"
), Value = c(NA, 4L, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA, NA)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```